# Should my iterable objects in Python also be the iterator like most examples

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

In most code examples of implementing `__iter__` in Python, I see them returning `self` instead of another object.  I know this is the required behavior for an iterator, but for an object that is an iterable, shouldn't it return something other than `self`?

My reasoning:  (GIL Aside, not CPU bound)

- If you have multiple threads iterating the same container, tracking your iterator progress in your iterable class (via the `__next__` method) will have values written from both threads, thus each loop will only get part of the data.
- Once your iterator/iterable object has been iterated once, you need to reset it. This can easily be done in `__iter__` but it seems to go against the grain of how I've seen other languages implement iterators.  I suppose it doesn't matter if it's idiomatic Python.

Any example I have in mind is a class called `Search` that uses an HTTP REST API to initialize a search.  Once it's done, you can do several things.

- Make the `Search` object iterable with `__iter__` returning self. NOT thread safe.
- Have the `Search` impliment `__iter__` that returns a different object that tracks iteration and queries results from the server as it needs. IS thread safe.
- Have a `results` method return an iterator/iterable `SearchResults` object that is NOT thread safe, but the method to get it IS thread safe.

Overall, what's the most robust way to implement an iterator in idiomatic Python that is thread safe.  Maybe I should even abstract the HTTP REST API to a cursor object like many database libraries (which would be like option 3).

Comment: It depends what you want to do.  If you want to have multiple independent iterators over the same data at the same time, then you don't want to make the iterable its own iterator.

Comment: Where are you seeing these examples?  Making an object its own iterator is always a bad idea for the reasons you give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `__iter__` protocol needs to return an iterator -- that can be either the same object (`self`, and `self` needs to have a `__next__` method), or another object (and that other object will have `__iter__` and `__next__`).

In just about all non-trivial use cases, a different and dedicated object should be returned for the iterator as it makes the whole process much simpler, easier to reason about, more likely to be thread-safe, etc.